# Adding service reference in VS 2017, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I add a service reference in VS 2017 MVC?

I've tried finding the add service reference button but its not there, there is only add reference and add connected services.

I've done adding service reference before in VS 2013, it was easy, but now I changed to VS 2017 for my school project and I have no clue on how to do it.

[Add > Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auwWA.png)

Comment: Have you tried for search at least? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

Comment: can you paste your screen capture of 'project-right click-add reference'?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried right clicking "References" and clicking "Add service reference"?

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov where do i go to search?

Comment: @WeiXiong google.com ? yahoo.com? any search engine?

Comment: @Keyur PATEL there wasnt any Add service reference option

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov yea i tried searching them up, even looking up on youtube, but there was barely any examples on VS 2017 and i tried those for 2017, didnt help

Comment: [This page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f295973f-5679-468d-8353-8ae26fa5889f/cannot-add-service-reference?forum=wcf) suggests several possible solutions, namely deleting the .suo and .sln.cache files (found in the solution directory) and restarting your project.

Comment: @Keyur PATEL okay thanks i will try that later

Comment: @WeiXiong http://take.ms/xgRMg

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov oh cool, ill try that when i get back to it, my laptop died

Comment: @WeiXiong seems you are opening this site as web site and not a solution

Comment: I opened a .sln file that my project member sent to me @Lei Yang

Comment: [Walkthrough: Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices -Version 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> Find '**References**' on '**Solution Explorer**' window

[image: References]

> Right click on '**References**', then you will see '**Add
>   Service Reference...**'

[image]

> Click '**Add Service Reference...**' then you will see another window.

[image]

Enter your webservice url. Then you will see smth in '**Services:**' panel. Select it give a name from '**Namespace:**', then click 'Ok'. That's all.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no References under this sln i have

Comment: seems you are opening this site as web site and not a solution

Comment: Option is missing for me too on a .NET 4.5.2 library which uses the new format csproj file (as used by .NET Standard projects). The option is present on a .NET library using the legacy csproj format.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add a answer for anyone encountering this problem in Visual Studio 2019. Right Click on Dependencies(less cluttered view) -> Add Connected Service.[image]

Click Microsoft WCF Web service Reference Provider.
[image]

Configure your web service.
[image]