# How do I make a POST web request in C# (SOAP)

Tags: c#, soap, http-post

I have to write a code that makes a post request with the data in the body.  I am not familiar with this sort of thing.

URI: https://___________________________________________________.asmx/Process

This is what I must send in the body:

Username:  ___________________

Passsword: ___________________

APISignature: _________________

MessageID: (a new GUID)

Data: Some XML.

Comment: The url end with ASMX. It's a web service. You now have to determine if it's a Soap or REST.  The google "How to consume a [soap/rest] webservice c# ?". The solution can range from add a service reference to use web client for POST. There is close to 0 chance that it's a Rest service based on the url and the Xml format.

Comment: Here is a good MSDN tutorial that will cover the creation and the consuption of a ASMX service. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308359/how-to-write-a-simple-web-service-by-using-visual-c-net

Comment: Thanks @xdtTransform - I have clarified with a colleague that it is SOAP.  That at least gives me a start point to research how to do it.

Comment: Please tell us what version of visual studio you use. It's essentially a 3 step process: 1) Right click References andchoose *Add [VS version dependent wording] Reference*, 2) paste asmx URL into box and click Go/Discover/Query/whatever, 3) Click OK. Then write code like `ActionServiceCLient asc = new ActionServiceClient(); asc.Process("myusername", "mypassword", "myapisig");` - yes, that simple

Comment: That should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137287/adding-service-reference-in-vs-2017-mvc and the mdsn documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb628652(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @CaiusJard VS Professional 2017

Answer (score 1):

- In VS 2017, right click references and choose Add Service Reference:

[image]

I will use sample calculator service at http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx

- Put the service URL in the box, click Go, choose a namespace, click OK:

[image]

- See the Connected Services node of Solution Explorer gained these things:

[image]

- Now write in code that uses the XXXClient (XXX is the name of your service) like:

[image]

- Highlighted are the operations of the service, arguments are the parameters to the operations, like Add(1,2)

VS makes a client that does all the HTTP and encoding of values etc; all you do is call the client methods, the XML is sent over the wire to the server, the response is decoded and the method returns

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I don't get anything under Connected Services except the namespace

Comment: Try following these steps exactly, including using the free online service mentioned - if it works out then it may be that your asmx service is not exporting a WSDL