# How to add a WCF connected service using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Was wondering how to add a connected WCF service URL reference in Visual Studio. When I click on Connected Services in my solution, I don't have the "Configure WCF Web Service Reference" option to click on under Connected services to add the service URL. I only have an option to configure Cloud storage. So, where do I find the "Configure WCF Web Service Reference" that used to be available in the find more services option? or is there another way to do it. Can someone help me? I'm using VS V2017.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click the references menu of the project, not the solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2017

https://therefore.net/help/2019/en-us/AR/SDK/WebAPI/the_webapi_guide_addservicereference.html

[Adding service reference in VS 2017, MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137287/adding-service-reference-in-vs-2017-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the "References" of the project and you can find the "Add Connected Service".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHI1M.png)